# General causes misalignments tikz plots in subfigures

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, subfloats

It regularly occurs that one of my tikz subfigure plots is misaligned. The tikz files are generated with Matlab and contain a lot of data. If I replace all the subfigures for identical example images, simple or identical tikz files, this does not occur. I generally do not have time to go through the 500+ lines of tikz code per figure every time this occurs, so I was wondering if there are general problems known about tikz figure misalignment that could cause this behaviour, such that it is easier for me to identify the problem.

I attach an example of an outcome, with corresponding subfigure code. As you can see, the bottom right figure is misaligned and the top left title as well (it's slightly higher).

[image]

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\scriptsize
\setlength\figureheight{4cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{6cm} 
\caption{knee Position}
\includetikz{balancingV1position}
%\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\label{fig::balancingV1position}
\end{subfigure}
~
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\scriptsize
\setlength\figureheight{4cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{6cm}
\caption{motor force}
\includetikz{balancingV1torque}
%\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\label{fig::balancingV1torque}
\end{subfigure}
~
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\scriptsize
\setlength\figureheight{4cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{6cm} 
\caption{nut velocity}
\includetikz{balancingV1velocity}
%\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\label{fig::balancingV1velocity}
\end{subfigure}
~
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\scriptsize
\setlength\figureheight{4cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{6cm}
\caption{\acs{com} angle}
\includetikz{balancingV1phi}
%\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\label{fig::balancingV1phi}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{text}
\label{fig::balancingV1}
\end{figure*}

% \includetikz is a new command that I've defined to load tikz files from a specific directory. It's not interesting.
% The purpose of this code is showing you the symmetry of the main code, I'm convinced that the problem occurs due to the tikz files, not here.
```

Let me stress once again that I'm looking for general known causes (and solutions), because I run into this problem occasionally and it seems randomly, hence why I'm not posting an MWE that contains a specific tikz file.

Comment: Not clear how anybody can be of much help if you won't share the code which you are convinced is responsible for the problem. If you generally do find the problem when you go through the code, what problems do you find?

Comment: My guess is there's a problem in `\includetikz` and the included figures are not equally sized.

Comment: To align the bottoms, you need to add a point to each plot (\path (axis rel cs: 0,-.2); for example) to force the plots to be the same distance from the bottom regarless of the labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try for example this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=3cm,height=3cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=2,ymin=0,ymax=2,ytick=0.5,xtick=0.5]
\end{axis}
\draw [red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=2,ymin=0,ymax=2,ytick=2,xtick=0.5]
\end{axis}
\draw [red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=2,ymin=0,ymax=2,ytick=1,xtick=2]
\end{axis}
\draw [red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=2,ymin=0,ymax=2,ytick=2,xtick=2]
\end{axis}
\draw [red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which generates this output:

[image]

As you can see, having ticks at the edge of the axis will modify the bounding box, as will having ticks (and axis labels) of different widths, cf. the two axes on the left. I think that is the reason why the caption is further away from the axis in your top left and bottom right plot.